# dynamic file name for mysql

Tags: command-line

```
mysql --host *HOST* --p   --user *USERNAME*  -e "query"  > file.lst
pause
```

My code looks as above. Is there a way to rename the `file.lst` and add sysdate at the end and make it like `file19072016.lst`? Assume that the date needs to be changed everyday and the file is run everyday.

Answer (score 3):

Do it using this command:

```
mysqldump -hlocalhost -uroot -p DBNAME > file$(date +"%d%m%Y").lst
```

Sample output:

```
file19072016.slt
```

Thanks to [@terdon](https://askubuntu.com/users/85695/terdon).
See edit history.

Answer (score 1):

You can create the desired file-name like so:

```
FILE="file`date +"%d%m%Y"`.lst"
```